# How do I store multiple pieces of individual data within a single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table which stores information about a group. Information such as the group name, group id, the number of members... However, I would also like to store the codes of each individual member within a group.

The way I initially tried to store the member codes was by creating individual columns. So I would have columns named `MemberCode1`, `MemberCode2`, `MemberCode3`. But the problem is a group can have 100 members which would mean 100 columns would be required to store the member codes individually.

My question: is there a way I can store an x amount of member codes within a single column within my table, or do simply make y columns and limit the number of users in a group to y?

Comment: You create a new table for storing Members which is connected with GroupID to your Groups. But I strongly suggest you first take some reading on basics of database design - [like this one](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Database+Design/72054/)

Comment: @NenadZivkovic will do. Thanks!

Comment: **Never ever** store more than one value in to a database cell - it **violates** the first normal form of relational database design and it's a horribly bad design choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a great example of when to use a separate table. You can create a second table, called "group", and store your group data there (group ID, group name).

I'm assuming that a member can belong to multiple groups, and a group can have many members.
If so, you can then have a table in the middle of those two tables to capture the members in each group. You can call this table "memberships" or "group_member" or something.

It would contain the Primary Keys of each of the entries in the member and group tables.

So your table structure could be:

- MEMBER (member ID... other fields)
- GROUP (group ID, group_name)
- MEMBERSHIP (member_id, group_id)

Finally, to find the number of members in each group:

```
SELECT group_id, COUNT(*)
FROM membership
GROUP BY group_id;
```

Or to get group data with that:

```
SELECT m.group_id, g.group_name, COUNT(m.*)
FROM membership m
INNER JOIN group g ON m.group_id = g.group_id
GROUP BY m.group_id;
```

Comment: Thanks bbrumm that's a great idea!

Comment: No problem, does the answer make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking it is not a good idea to store multiple pieces of information in the same field. It violates normal form and, more practically, it is hard to maintain.

The best solution to your issue would be to create a separate table for the members (`Member`) and include a foreign key, perhaps `groupID` or `group_id`, referring to the group table (`Group`).

In the event that a "member" can belong to more than one "group", you would create a third table, `MemberGroup`, with a composite primary key (`member_id`, `group_id`) made up of foreign keys referring to `Member` and `Group` respectively.